# Convert 10-14 V DC to 1-5 V DC (Current rating of 4 - 20 mA)

Tags: voltage, digital-logic

I am a beginner to Electronics. I am working on a circuit board whose Input source is a 10-14 V DC. Using this input I want an output of 1-5 V or 4-20 mA input so that I can scale it down for my LCD display.
Please share any ideas to convert supply voltage to a 4-20 mA output so that I can use it in my projects

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to EE.SE. It appears that English is not your first language (you should indicate this in your user profile or in the question) and your question is not clear.

I am reading your question as, "*How can I convert a DC battery voltage reading - range 10 V to 14 V - to a 1 - 5 V or a 4 - 20 mA signal?*"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHjrtd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) 3:1 Voltage divider. (b) 4-20mA conversion.*

- For feeding to a 1-5V analog input a 3:1 divider provides the simplest solution. At 10 V you will get 3.3 V in and at 14 V you will get 4.67 V in. Although this isn't using the full range of your analog input it might be adequate. I have suggested 2 x 1k resistors rather than a non-standard 2k for the top portion of the divider.
- Since you can accept 1-5V or 4-20mA I am guessing that your device can be configured to 4-20mA by adding a jumper or switch for an internal 250 Ω resistor. By adding a 500 Ω resistor in series with this you will get 20 mA at 15 V.

---

Note that the SI units convention is 'V' or 'volt', 'A' or 'amp'. Units named after a person are capitalised when abbrevieated and lowercase when spelled out.